# .net Maui custom MapHandler

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I want to make custom renderes, or handlers as it is in Maui, and it works for Android, but I cannot make it work on iOS.

I make a very basic custom map class with a method to tilt the view of the map.

```
public class CustomMap : Map
{
    public void Tilt()
    {
        (this.Handler as CustomMapHandler).Tilt();
    }
}
```

In shared code I define a MapHandler as

```
public partial class CustomMapHandler : MapHandler
{
    public partial void Tilt();
}
```

And the android version is

```
public partial class CustomMapHandler : MapHandler
{
    private GoogleMap thisMap;
    protected override void ConnectHandler(MapView nativeView)
    {
        base.ConnectHandler(nativeView);

        nativeView.GetMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback(map =>
        {
            thisMap = map;
        }));
    }

    public partial void Tilt()
    {
        var z = thisMap.CameraPosition.Zoom + 3;
        var cu = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(new LatLng(55, 12), z, 65, 0));
        thisMap.AnimateCamera(cu, 10000, null);
    }
}
//Not showing the OnMapReadyCallback as it is irrrelevant for the question, and works as it is
```

In MauiProgram I setup mapping and custom map as well as custom handler as

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .UseMauiMaps()
    .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
    {
        handlers.AddHandler<CustomMap, CustomMapHandler>();
    })
```

This all works, as the simplistic test, it is, for Android.
I can add the customMap to a page and call Tilt and it tilts.

For iOS I am failing to even make it start, but i am doing this

```
public partial class CustomMapHandler : MapHandler
{
    // private MKMapView thisMap;

    protected override void ConnectHandler(object nativeMap)
    {
        base.ConnectHandler(nativeMap);
    }
    public partial void Tilt(){}
}
```

This does compile and deploy (can only test on emulator right now), but then fails with

**System.TypeLoadException:** 'Could not set up parent class, due to: Invalid generic instantiation assembly:/Users/clouddash/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FB9E6386-C76F-41BD-9FCC-A15670D0ADDC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E34C0314-6D81-457B-99A3-9CD643CEFD86/MauiMapTest.app/Microsoft.Maui.dll type:ViewHandler`2 member:(null)'

In

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(AppDelegate)); //here
}
```

I am using net8 and the Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps 8.0.7

It is unclear if I am missing something in code or setup, as I have been unable to find any known issues like mine.

Comment: Do you have location permission in `Info.plist`?

Comment: I do. I am fairly certain a missing permission would look different, but I have both
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> and
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>

Comment: The thing is that your exception is incomplete so its very hard to judge what the issue is!

Comment: I added the remaining bits of the exception, which cut cut on copy paste before

Comment: Umm, I wanted the stack trace... Always add the stack trace whenever possible, Also it seems that the MapHandler is internally throwing an exception for some reason, Also are you on .NET 7?

Comment: There is actually no callstack beyond > 0xD in MauiMapTest.Program.Main at D:\User\Desktop\MauiMapTest\Platforms\iOS\Program.cs:13,13 C#
I just double checked, and I am on net8.

Comment: You might want to create a Github repo for this it could be a bug

Comment: Here is an example of using MapHandler on GitHub : [MauiSamples
/MauiMaps](https://github.com/VladislavAntonyuk/MauiSamples/tree/main/MauiMaps). This might help.